# Use of genitive, prepositional, and instrumental cases in Russian

Tags: грамматика

Can anyone clarify the uses of these cases in Russian? (Sorry if this area is for more advanced questions, I am new here!). Also I have studied Latin and have knowledge of its case system.

Is genitive always used after "из" ? (ex "я из америки")

Why is the genitive used in "Мне бы хотелось чая" ? If I understand properly this means "I would like some tea"

Also are instrumental and prepositional analogous to ablative in Latin? (I know accusative is also used after certain prepositions in Latin).

спасибо!

Comment: Ashley, welcome, you are asking at least about three different, though related issues. I guess it's better to start with something one and then see how it goes with other questions if they will arise.